# django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetag

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

Traceback (most recent call last):
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 644, in run_with_reloader
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 629, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 334, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
    return [
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 171, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 44, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 17, in get_template_directories
    for backend in engines.all():
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/ilya/projects/react/todo_django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': No module named 'pytz'
```

Вот эту ошибку я словил изучая как соединить реакт с джанго. Как я немного понял я както нафурычил с django-rest. Я вроде как действовал строго по тутору. Как вы думаете что случилось?

Древо приложения:

[image: Древо приложения]

Древо главной части(я не заю как это назвать)
[image: Древо главной части]

Код api/views

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView 
from rest_framework.response import Response


class TestAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,req,*args,**kwargs):
        data = [{id=1,text="Hello",isdone=False},{id=2,text="World",isdone=False}]
        return Response(data)
```

urls(mainapp)

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views as vw

urlpatterns = [
    path('',vw.indexView)
    path('api/',include('mainapp.api.urls'))
]
```

urls(mainapp/api)

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views as vw

urlpatterns = [
    path('test',vw.TestAPIView.as_view(),name='test'),
]
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-*%ns!v_59ag05^k=rt6=_bye!!ou2c#pa0+62(^evntssba^)h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainapp',
    'rest_framework'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR/'templates'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'media') 
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/static'))
]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

подскажите пожалуйста я хочу дальше изучать этот стэк)

МАЛЕНЬКАЯ ПРАВКА:
не знаю меняет ли это дело но я на manjaro linux(ну а вдруг)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исходя из ошибки и не особо углубляясь в смысл кода и логики, то в том пространстве где вы запускаете `django` всего навсего не хватает библиотки `pytz`. Вам наверное известно как устанавливать пакеты, но для тех кто не в курсе

```
pip install pytz
```

Данная команда использует `pip`, может быть `pip3` в зависмости от..., настроек, виртуального пространства и прочего
Полная документация по установке через pip и ссылка на проект лежит [здесь](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)

Comment: Спасибо) Как-то не додумался)